# Trait with same method as Class , one Static

Tags: php, static, traits

```
trait TestTrait
{
    public function matches()
    {

    }
}


class TestClassOne
{
    public static function matches()
    {

    }

}

class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne
{
    use TestTrait {
        matches as alternativeMatches;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->alternativeMatches();
    }
}
```

When calling the method run as seen above it will return the error :Fatal error: Cannot make static method **matches** non static

The classes are not written by me and the trait I have used in multiple other locations.  A hell if I have to rewrite the trait .. or have to make a new one , just to make it work with this class.

Is there a way to make it work ?

Cheers

Comment: I think you should add your update as an answer and also accept it. If somebody finds a better solution you could still change that later, but until then this is probably as good as it gets for future visitors.

Comment: @Yoshi .. I will do that, thanks for answering.

Comment: From the little code you posted, the troublemaker is `TestClassOne::matches()`. Do you have any good reason to make it `static`?

Comment: @axiac :  as stated , I did not write the class..  It is a vendor class....

Comment: In this case maybe it's better to not inherit `TestClassTwo` from `TestClassOne` but embed one `TestClassOne` object into it. [Favor composition over inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=favor+composition+over+inheritance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I made it work with a bit of a hack ... but I do not like it...
Someone has a nicer way of doing this ?

```
class TestClassTwo extends TestClassOne
    {
        use TestTrait {
            matches as alternativeMatches;
        }

        public function run()
        {
            $this->alternativeMatches();
        }

         public static function matches()
        {
            parent::matches();
        }

    }
```